# VirtualBox using LUKS for root and shrinking

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, luks

So I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in a VirtualBox. Using setup, I encryptet the whole / partition.

The disc is dynamic, and up to 200GB. I am using less than 20GB according to `df -h`, 180 GB are free on my `/`.

After some time, I wanted to shrink the vm like I always did. Startet in recovery, and run `dd if=/dev/zero of=dump bs=100M; rm dump`.
So afterwards, my .vdi file occupied 200GB on my drive. That was unexpected, as this command did not really make my .vdis bigger before, but that must be the encryption.

So after shutting down the vm and checking free space on /, I run `VBoxManage modifyhd --compact myvdi.vdi`, which seems to run fine, but not shrink the file.

My guess is, that I have the encrypted zero-file now, which luks does not delete for any reason.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was not able to shrink the lvm container manually.

But I was able to add the `discard="true"` option to the .vbox file, which looked like

```
<AttachedDevice nonrotational="true" discard="true" type="HardDisk" port="1" device="0">
    <Image uuid="{3836a042-a83e-4000-9a59-e95ad65162ce}"/>
</AttachedDevice>
```

After booting again now, I was able to run `fstrim` and the .vdi file was shrunk.

---

Actually, I had some [problems](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=75308) using this option before, so I wanted to do this by hand.

I highly recommend making a backup, as I killed my .vdi file and was not able to restore. Also I disabled the option again later, and checked the filesystem before I deleted my backup.

---

There is some more information [here](https://superuser.com/questions/646559/virtualbox-and-ssds-trim-command-support).